# How to insert a line similar to a Trend Line in Spotfire?

Tags: spotfire

Is it possible to add a 45-degree straight line over an existing scatter plot in Spotfire? If yes, then how?

[A straight line like in the given image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW1GP.png)

Comment: That line usually means something or is derived from a formula such as K-Means Clustering or another method to show outliers, or the operating range, or a multitude of other things. It isn't just a fictions line.

Comment: @scsimon I know that such lines can only be generated using some mathematical formulation. But in my case I want a simple 45 degree straight  line as I want to show that the variable on Y-axis is more/less inconstant than the variable on X-axis. So, I want a fiction line only. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write "x" in the Curve expression box (available under "Lines & Curves" property's "Curve draw" option). It will plot a 45 degree straight line over an existing scatter plot.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way of adding an overlay is to use the functionality in the "Lines & Curves" property page. In there, there is a variety of different overlays that can be added. In the image below, I have added a "Curve draw" line to the plot.

If none of the available overlays is an immediate fit for you, then you migth be able to use the "Line from column values" or the "Curve from data table" options. The content of such a data table or column can be calculated from a data function if desired.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Prior to post this question I also tried to use these options listed the "Lines & Curves" property, but I couldn't get anything as per my requirement. Now, I have got the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Prior to post this question I also tried to use these options listed the "Lines & Curves" property, but I couldn't get anything as per my requirement. Now, I have got the answer. I used the same option (i.e, Curve Draw) and just wrote "**x**" in the _Curve expression_ box. This serves the purpose. Thank you.

Comment: @AkPandya - No problem, glad you found a solution. Perhaps you can mark the answer as accepted? Cheers!